# Placing aligned buttons inside column next to text box

Tags: html, css

Apologies)

I'm struggling to find a solution to placing two buttons in a column (or two columns?) aligned to a text box to the left of them.  I've done this by creating a rect within a colunm then adding the buttons (aligned) floating to the right.  Looks fine in a desktop screen but once sized down to mobile the buttons (not being in columns) fall apart. I've attached a screenshot of the page: one row has an attempt but the buttons are placed over the existing column (text box) in the row.  It's quite possibly staring me in the face but I can't see it!

Here's a snippet for the row and column:

````html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8 col-md-6 white-rect mr-4  ">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Book flights.
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                            <button type="button" class="btn my-primary btn-sm my-small-btn">COMPLETE</button>
                    
                            <button type="button" class="btn my-primary2 btn-sm my-small-btn"> DELETE </button>
                    </div>
                </div>```

And here's the code for the the row with the buttons that are aligned in desktop but are effectively floating outside a column:

```<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8 col-md-6 white-rect mr-4">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                Reschdule Twitter Meeting.
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <button type=".button" class="btn my-primary btn-sm my-small-btn">COMPLETE</button>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>
                    <button type=".button" class="btn my-primary2 btn-sm my-small-btn"> DELETE </button>
                </div>
````

[image: Screenshot of the page]

Many thanks.

Comment: Use CSS grid for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might need to adjust the numbers, but something like this is how I would do it:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    grid-gap: 24px;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr) minmax(max-content, 1fr);
  }
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </div>

  <div class="buttons-container">
    <button class="button">complete</button>
    <button class="button">delete</button>
  </div>
  

  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </div>

  <div class="buttons-container">
    <button class="button">complete</button>
    <button class="button">delete</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </div>

  <div class="buttons-container">
    <button class="button">complete</button>
    <button class="button">delete</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" class="input">
  </div>

  <div class="buttons-container">
    <button class="button">complete</button>
    <button class="button">delete</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks Henrique - I'll give that a whirl in the morning. Can I pretty much adapt my own styling around that?  I've got borders and colours on the text box and buttons to adhere to is all.  Is 'section' still relevant with regard to Bootstrap 4 (that may be an irrelevant question to be fair).  Seems like a neater way to group that 'form' together.  Many thanks.

Comment: Section is a semantic html tag, using bootstrap or not doesn't have any effect on it. I focused only on the overall structure in the example, so you can pretty much add any presentation styling you want on top of it.

Comment: Thanks Henrique - sounds like a neat solution. I'll have a go at it and return back. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok - this is a much neater solution thanks.  However, I need the input container and buttons to be reponsive (so as I move down to mobile size the buttons are shifted into one column. I understand the process but as the code has become a little more complex (for me at the moment) I'm struggling to see where I fit the 'col-lg col-mb col-sm' etc).

Comment: You don't fit any of that. Those are classes from bootstrap's grid system, I'm assuming, right? You don't need it here, since this is made with css grid. You can alter the grid using media-queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). For a reference about how to use display grid, you can check: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Thanks Henrique - the Grid method (from what I've read) seems quite exciting and elegant but I'm struggling to find a method that enables the input and button containers to 'shrink' when the screen size changes (this needs to be built for mobile first). I guess using Bootstrap I'd use columns (we were taught basic bootstrap before this app was left to us to develop) but trying @media in CSS I can't find a method yet.  Apologies - this question has probably veered off course - do I need to start a new question? Many thanks.

Comment: I edited the snippet to add a media-query. It should be more than enough to be considered fully responsive like this. Try not to focus too much on bootstrap, and take a look a proper css styling.

Comment: Ahh - that works very well.  I'll digest your new snippet so I can work it out myself through playing over it. I do prefer to work witrh CSS than over rely on Bootstrap. Thank you very much Henrique.  I'll consider this well and truly answered!